# Using pandas to combine rows in excel sheets while avoiding duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have extracted two columns from two different excel sheets.  Both the columns are a list of names.  I would like to compare column1 to column2 and add any names to column1 that aren't in column2 without duplicating existing names.  Should I use a loop to accomplish this or is there a built in function I can use?

```
df_1=pd.read_excel("excel sheet")
df_2=pd.read_excel("sheet 2")

df1.iloc[:,[3]]
df1.dropna().drop_duplicates()

df_company_list.iloc[:,[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are interested only in getting a column of unique names, it's as simple as

   ```
   new_col = pd.concat(df1[col1], df2[col2]).drop_duplicates()
   ```
2. It's more complicated to keep the first column or data frame intact when it itself contains duplicates. I can think of something like this:

   ```
   unique_names = df1[col1].unique()                          # np.array
   idx = df2[col2].apply(lambda x : x not in unique_names)    # boolean array
   df_final = df1.append(df2[idx])                            # data frame
   # or 
   col_final = df1[col1].append(df2.loc[idx,col2])            # single column
   ```

   But `apply` is essentially a loop.

---

BTW, your code

```
df1.iloc[:,[3]]
df1.dropna().drop_duplicates()
```

doesn't modify `df1`. You may have wanted `df1 = df1.iloc[:,[3]]`.

Comment: what is `col1`?  Getting an error `NameError: name 'col1' is not defined`

Comment: It's the name or index of your column.

Comment: well actually, i stripped the column i needed with `df1.iloc` so i don't need an index really.

Comment: Also, btw solution 2 is def what I need.  I have duplicates in the first df.

Comment: Uhm, not quite sure what you mean... Doesn't it solve your problem?